# Install HTML5 Boilerplate on Rails 4

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4

I used some HTML5 commands on Rails 4.0. Since I am a newbie to Rails, I am unable to figure out what went wrong with the stuff. I think HTML5 Boilerplate hasn't been installed on the system. The command used by me was:

```
p
Week:  
<%=week_field_tag :week %>  
/p
```

[image: my output]

[image: desired output, look at week text area in the browser]

the upper one is "the output of written command" and the down one is the "desired output"

Comment: What is the expected output of the code you put? Can you please update your question with the rendered HTML source and any JavaScript console errors you receive in the browser?

Comment: @LeonStafford the output was  
date [       ] (where [] means text box)  
while it should ouput a drop down box which on clicking shows the inbuild calender where one can select the required week....

Comment: could you please update your question with that complete output code, so we can see the rendered HTML, it is still difficult to discern what you are expecting and what you are generating

Comment: @LeonStafford Is the question clear now??

Comment: @LeonStafford dude got it.....  
actually firefox doesn't support these stuff at all.....  
while chrome and opera does...

Comment: ok, I still wasn't clear at all, so glad you got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually firefox doesn't support these stuff at all.....
while chrome and opera does.....